# Font size is set to px instead of pt in the text editor of the ribbon

Tags: 2013, ribbon, sharepoint-server

When I edit a page, in the ribbon next to the font drop-down list I can pick how large the font should be. By default, this is set to **px** in my environment.

I've never changed this to px and I have absolutely no idea how to put it in pt. But it would only be logical if it were in **pt**, so if anyone knows how I can change this setting so that it shows pt, I'd be really happy.

Example of what it looks like in my environment:

[image: Px instead of pt]

Example of what I want the font size to show:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the font size from PX to PT. Select the text to which you want to apply the font size, then in the Font Size drop down, just type the size you want followed by PT and press "Enter", now the font size will be applied in "PT" and not in "PX".

[image: Size in PX]

[image: Entering the size in PT]

Comment: This will not change it on a site level as the OP was looking for

Comment: This does indeed not change it on a site level, what I need is a more permanent solution where a user will never have to see the font size in **px**. I just want it to be in **pt** all the time.